# What type of token that system.out.println() is in Java?

Tags: java, token

I have a homework problem that asks me to show the full sequence of tokens in a Java program.

From what I know, There is Five Types of Tokens

1)Reserve Word or Keywords such as int, public, break, class etc

2)Identifier such as age, sum etc

3)Literals such as 212, 11.5, e2.0 etc.

4)Operators such as +, -, /, * etc.

5)Separators such as $,?,# etc.

However, I am confused at what type of token that 'System.out.println()' in Java is ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: as with functional code in general, it is not a *single* token.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

```java
System    // Identifier (class)
.         // Separator
out       // Identifier (variable)
.         // Seperator
println() // Identifier (method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers with separators between them.

I think.

System, out and println are identifiers,
All the rest are separators.

Answer (score -3):

System.out.println() is a keyword token as it is reserved in the language.
Thanks.

Comment: [Sure about that?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Comment: Don't joke with me. I am sure copletely.

Comment: lol ok, not sure you understand the concept of a "keyword", but whatever makes you happy my friend.